# Python printing the value of the variable show <__main__.Element object at 0x10071d5d0>

Tags: python

Hi I am trying to print the value of "temp" variable so I use print(temp)

```
def delete_first(self):
    if self.head:
        deleted_element = self.head
        temp = deleted_element.next
        print(temp)
        self.head = temp
        return deleted_element
    else:
        return None
```

Why do I get an output like this? Is this that the object address in the memory? do I fix it so that it prints out more meaningful/readable object names?

```
  <__main__.Element object at 0x10071d5d0>
```

Full code:

```
class Element(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None


class LinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self, head=None):
        self.head = head

    def append(self, new_element):
        current = self.head
        if self.head:
            while current.next:
                current = current.next
            current.next = new_element
        else:
            self.head = new_element

    def insert_first(self, new_element):
        new_element.next = self.head
        self.head = new_element

    def delete_first(self):
        if self.head:
            deleted_element = self.head
            temp = deleted_element.next
            print(temp)
            self.head = temp
            return deleted_element
        else:
            return None


class Stack(object):
    def __init__(self, top=None):
        self.ll = LinkedList(top)

    def push(self, new_element):
        self.ll.insert_first(new_element)

    def pop(self):
        return self.ll.delete_first()


# Test cases
# Set up some Elements
e1 = Element(1)
e2 = Element(2)
e3 = Element(3)
e4 = Element(4)

# Start setting up a Stack
stack = Stack(e1)

# Test stack functionality
stack.push(e2)
stack.push(e3)
print stack.pop().value
print stack.pop().value
print stack.pop().value
print stack.pop()
stack.push(e4)
print stack.pop().value
```

Full output:

<**main**.Element object at 0x10071d5d0>
3
<**main**.Element object at 0x10071d590>
2
None
1
None
None
4

Comment: Define either `__repr__` or `__str__` to return a string that you want to show when you print an `Element`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to define a `__str__` method for this class (if you own it, of course), like the `toString()` in Java.

For example:

```
class Element():
  attr_1 = 0
  attr_2 = 0
  def __str__(self):
    return '%s, %s' % (self.attr_1, self.attr_2)
```

Comment: Nice try but that doesn't return a string.

Comment: Also it's using class attributes instead of instance attributes, it doesn't inherit from `object`, and it's missing `self` qualifiers for attribute lookup.